# Google Sheets Mapping

Tags: google-maps, google-sheets, mapping

Using data from Google Sheets and Google Maps API is it possible to create a map with the route outlined, the stops indicated and beneath the map have the specifics about the routes such as?

Start here, at this time
First Stop, at this time, distance from previous stop
Second Stop, at this time, distance from previous stop
End here, at this time

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is [Google My Maps](http://www.google.com/mymaps/). You can use this hidden feature to add lines, points, shapes, directions and labels to a snippet of a Google Map (Street, Satellite or Hybrid). It is then saved to your Google Drive where I presume you can embed it into a Google Sheets spreadsheet.

I hope this helps.